# Post multiple forms with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have multiple forms in my page. I'd like to be able to post those forms from single Jquery function.

It only work for the first form. I think this is because all forms have the same Id, I would need to use click function() instead of submit() and use something like $(this).closest("form") ...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="fpostcomm">
<input name="cmt" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputcommt" autocomplete="off">
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fpostcomm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({type:"POST", data: $(this).serialize(), url:"ajax/ajxaaddcmt.php", 
            success: function(data){
                $("#inputcommt").val('');
            },
                        error: function(){
                    alert ("Error.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use classes instead. IDs are supposed to be _unique_ and ID selector only selects the first matched element.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reuse IDs. They must be unique in a document. Fix that and you can then grab them however you need.

If you want a single shared name on all of them, use a class instead.

```
<form class="form-horizontal fpostcomm" role="form">
<input name="cmt" type="text" class="form-control input-sm inputcommt" autocomplete="off">
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fpostcomm").submit(function(){
        $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({type:"POST", data: $(this).serialize(), url:"ajax/ajxaaddcmt.php", 
            success: function(data){
                $form.find(".inputcommt").val('');
            },
            error: function(){
                    alert ("Error.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```